# multiprocessing.Pool.map function doesn't see variables in global namespace

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, global

This toy script fails:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def myFunc1(x):
    return x+c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
    b = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    result = pool.map(myFunc1,b)
    for i in range(len(result)):
        print(result[i])
```

with error

```
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aldo.dottavio\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\aldo.dottavio\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\aldo.dottavio\Projects\THEIAA\2020-02 parallel processing\untitled0.py", line 12, in myFunc1
    return x+c
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\aldo.dottavio\Projects\THEIAA\2020-02 parallel processing\untitled0.py", line 19, in <module>
    result = pool.map(myFunc1,b)

  File "C:\Users\aldo.dottavio\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()

  File "C:\Users\aldo.dottavio\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value

NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

I expected to get

```
[[2,3]
 [4,5]]
[[6,7]
 [8,9]]
```

as the result, but instead *c* is undefined in *myFunc1*. I think that this is caused by *map*, and that by using *map* to apply *myFunc1* to the data, *myFunc1* loses access to the global namespace.

A similar toy script succeeds:

```
import numpy as np

def myFunc1(x):
    return x+c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
    b = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
    result = myFunc1(b)
    for i in range(len(result)):
        print(result[i])
```

and outputs the result

```
[[2 3]
 [4 5]]
[[6 7]
 [8 9]]
```

as expected.

The above is just to illustrate the problem; in the actual script, the function is more complicated and must be iterated over thousands of matrices.

The variables I need from the global namespace are parameters used by the function; they are not changed by any of the processes and are the same for all function calls - they are read only at this point in the script.

How can I access global variables from the function in *map*? I don't want to make copies of the parameters - the parameters are only ~1 MB of data, but I could have 15,000 or so elements in the iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using *starmap* and *itertools.product()*

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import product

def myFunc1(x,c):
    return x+c

if __name__ == '__main__':

    c = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
    b = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    result = pool.starmap(myFunc1,product(b,[c]))
    # result = myFunc1(b)
    for i in range(len(result)):
        print(result[i])
```

Using *itertools.product* and [ ] around *c* allows passing the entire array *c* as a one-element iterable, instead of iterating  over the first index of the NumPy array.